# Result of IF statement nested in WHILE loop confusing me (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, while-loop, boolean-logic

Here's my full code (javascript):

```
var products = ["Choo Choo Chocolate", "Icy Mint", "Cake Batter", "Bubblegum"];
var hasBubbleGum = [false, false, false, true];
var i = 0;

while (i < hasBubbleGum.length) {
    if (hasBubbleGum[i]) {
        console.log(products[i] + " contains bubblegum");
    }
    i = i + 1;
}
```

This code returns to the console:

```
Bubblegum contains bubblegum
```

What confuses me is this IF statement nested in my while loop. I know this code is correct but I don't understand why it's bypassing the IF statement when hasBubbleGum is set to FALSE.

My original thought was that printing to the console would yield:

```
Choo Choo Chocolate has bubblegum
Icy Mint has bubblegum
Cake Batter has bubblegum
Bubblegum has bubblegum
```

Am I missing a key fundamental idea that IF statements ignore boolean values of FALSE?

Comment: Please show us the entire loop. We don't see the closing braces so there may be more statements before them. In particular we can't see what's happening, if anything, to your index variable `i`.

Comment: an IF checks if the condition is true or false.  Since `hasBubbleGum[0]` is false, the IF resolves to FALSE, and will generally try to process the `else` (which there appears to be none - your code appears incomplete) .. so it does nothing ... increase counter (also not shown, but I'm assuming it's in there somewhere), go to next iteration.  The "output" only shows when it finds the TRUE value on index 4

Comment: I apologize I completely forgot to complete the loop in my post

Comment: Consider strongly learning to use an object oriented style. Parallel arrays of related items are a Bad Idea. `var products = { { name: 'gum', hasBubblesGum: true }, { name: 'chocolate', hasBubbleGum: false } ... }`

Comment: I'm new to Javascript and programming in general. The book I'm currently reading from (Head First Javascript) has been foreshadowing objects for a few chapters now but I am currently in the arrays chapter. This code is from the book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I missing a key fundamental idea that IF statements ignore boolean values of FALSE?

Yes, you are. This is the entire point of `if`. In most languages, `if` statements follow the following pattern:

```
if (expression) then {statements}
```

with the `then` being implied, rather than typed out, in many languages. The `{statements}` are only executed **if** the `(expression)` is `true` or 'thruthy' for languages that allow implisit casting to `boolean` or lack a native `boolean` type. For example `0` is considered `false` in many languages, and anything not `0` to be `true`.

Your `hasBubbleGum[i]` is an expression which will return a `boolean` value depending on the contents of the array at index `i`. Your confusion may have come from not understanding what conditional expressions like `==` do; they simply are "special functions" which return either `true` or `false` based on their operands.

`if` statements are one of the fudamental [Control Flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow) primitives. The objective of flow-control statements is that they "control the flow of program execution" based on some condition. A `while` loop is also a control flow statement; The code inside its scope is executed in a loop so long as its condition remains true.

Answer (score 2):

The code is correct, actually the only product set to `true` is `"Bubblegum"`.

If you want your desired result you should change your bool mask as follows:

```
var hasBubbleGum = [true, true, true, true];
```

There's nothing wrong in the `if` statement, the only condition that is `true` is your last `hasBubbleGum` bool array.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't understand why it's bypassing the IF statement when hasBubbleGum is set to FALSE.

It's not bypassing the `if` statement: The `if` statement executes, evaluates its condition (`hasBubbleGum[i]`), sees that the resulting value is `false`, and so doesn't execute the statement attached to it. The `if` runs, but since `hasBubbleGum` is false for all entries except `i = 3`, you don't see any output for the other entries, just for `i = 3`.

Comment: Ohhhhh ok this makes sense. IF statements were not tricky when the statement inside the parentheses compared two values with comparison operators but when i got to this IF statement it through me for a loop (pun intended).

Comment: @jake.wies: Ah, yes, with you. Side note: The bit within the parentheses is an *expression*, not a *statement*. In JavaScript, the expression gets evaluated and then (if necessary) coerced to a boolean (in your case it wasn't necessary, because the values in the array were booleans). In the coercion, anything "falsey" is considered false. Those values are `0`, `""`, `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`, and of course `false`. Anything else is "truthy" and the `if` goes into the statement attached to it.